# How do I use system.assert, system.assertequals, system.run as in my unit test?

Tags: apex, unit-test

I am new to Salesforce. I wrote test class for below program, but it is simple. I want to make use of `system.assert()`, `system.assertequals()` and `system.runas()` commands methods for the below test method, to better understand their use. Please help me with this by providing examples of where I should implement them into my test test class as I complete it.

```
APEX CLASS
public class testinterview {

    public String getOutput() {
        return null;
    }

public string fname{set;get;}
public patient__c pt{set;get;}
public list<patient__c> pat{set;get;}

public testinterview()
{
}
public void input()
{
pt=new Patient__c();
pt.FirstName__c=fname;
insert pt;
}

public void output()
{
pat= new list<patient__c>();
 pat=[select Firstname__c from Patient__c ];
}

}
```

TEST CLASS I HAVE WRITTEN

```
@isTest
private class mytest{
static testMethod void testinterviewTest() {


testinterview inter=new testinterview();
inter.input();
inter.output();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

From [System Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) Apex documentation:

[System.assert()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assert): Asserts that the specified condition is true. If it is not, a fatal error is returned that causes code execution to halt.

[System.assertEquals()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_assertEquals): Asserts that the first two arguments are the same. If they are not, a fatal error is returned that causes code execution to halt

[System.runAs()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm#apex_System_System_runAs_2): Changes the current user to the specified user. (execute the test as a given user)

Please see the [Testing Example of the Apex Code Developer Guide](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_testing_example.htm)

As a simplistic example consider the following class:

```
public class GreetingClass {
     public String sayHello(String first_name){
           return "Hello "+first_name;
     }
}
```

And the following is a test method for that class:

```
@isTest
private class testGreetings {
    static testMethod void testSayHello(){
            GreetingClass greeting = new GreetingClass();
            // you can add a System.runAs() here wrapping this call to get outcomes for a given user
            // test that sending 'Joe' as parameter to the sayHello method, the output is 'Hello Joe'
            System.assertEquals(greeting.sayHello('Joe'),'Hello Joe')
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter really but I think the expected value is supposed to come first, like `System.assertEquals('Hello Joe',greeting.sayHello('Joe'))`